# Move content database SharePoint 2010 404 error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, content-database

**I get a 404 page not found error after I run a mount-spcontentdatabase command.**

I have Production SharePoint 2010 farm with application server, Front end and application server installed on windows 2008 r2 and SQL Server 2008 r2. 
 I need to move the Farm to a Windows Server 2012 Environment with SQL Server R2 environment.

*Following are the steps I have taken*

a) Install Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition on all the three servers i.e.  FrontEnd Server , App server and Database server

b) Install SharePoint on App server and Front end Server with  SharePoint 2010 sp2 with the following service accounts

i) sp_admin - for install

ii) Sp_farm to create and join the farm

ii) sp_web for the web application

c) Installed Cumulative updates on the app servers and front end server

d) Installed SQL server 2012 R2 on the database server

e) took a backup of the content sql server (2008) database and restored in the sql server 2012 database

f) created a web application on port 80 deleted the content database  and did a mount-spcontentdatabase.

g) The mount power-shell script-let ran without any errors  but i get a 404 page not found.

h) I did a dismount and mount-spcontentdatabase - same error

i) I did a stsadm - o deletecontentdb and and stsadm -o addcontentdb but same results.

j) I don't get any errors is the ulsviewer log files and there is no error in the event logs or the sql logs

Test-spcontentdatabase gave me some errors like missingsetupfile, missing site defintion . but also suggests that it is a non upgrade error equals false.

1) Is the move from SQL server 2008 to SQL server  2012 supported by Microsoft?.Is there any tech-net article for the same.

2) IS detach the database and reattach the database the correct method rather than sql backup and restore .
3) Is there any power-shell script to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: Do the following: IISRESET and check alternate access mapping

Comment: Try to create an empty ContentDatabase and a TeamSite-Collection in CentralAdministration. Then browse to your site and see if you still get the 404-Error. This will make things clearer if you have a configuration-problem in SharePoint or if it is a problem with the database.